# Unable to deploy OWD change on Streaming Channel object

Tags: deployment, owd

I'm trying to make the OWD on the StreamingChannel object as private. However, when trying to deploy the StreamingChannel object, I get the following error message:

"Custom Object Definition ID: bad value for restricted picklist field: StreamingChannel"

I don't know how to fix this issue since there is no picklist field on this object at all.

Comment: Do you see this issue in scratch org? If yes check steps mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000352577&type=1)

Comment: No, my issue is between developer sandboxes, dev to int.